# Seeking Hosting provider recommendation for Ektron sites

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

We have a lot of Ektron 8.0.1 sites on several servers and we are researching new hosting companies. We are looking for a host that will truly "partner" with us instead of forcing us to figure out how to configure/tweak/troubleshoot the servers.

Anyone have any recommendations for Ektron friendly hosting providers?

I also posted this at http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=41805

Thanks,
Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I work for Ektron.)

Before I started working for Ektron, though, I was an Ektron customer. Speaking strictly as a former customer, we worked with ServerSide.net. They're very good at Ektron and partnering in the way you describe. Able to help with everything we needed and more.

Comment: As it turns out, a co-worker had found Serverside.net and had already gotten a quote from them.  So that avenue is looking good.